# Phalcon PHP PDO BIND causes empty result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

I'm playing with Phalcon PHP library at the moment,

when i use PDO bind in the parameters in GamesModel I no longer get a result, any ideas?

I'm working [through this](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-models)

**View: (json_output.phtml)**

```
echo $output->active;
```

**Model:**

```
class GamesModel extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource("games");
    }

    /**
        Returns the status of a game found by ID
        @param $id The game ID
    */
    public function getStatusById( $id )
    {

        $result = GamesModel::query()
            ->where("id = :id:")
            ->bind( array("id" => $id) )
            ->execute();

        //$result = GamesModel::findFirst(3);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class GameController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller 
{

     private $gamesModel;

     public function initialize()
     {
        $this->gamesModel = new GamesModel();
     }   

    public function getStatusByIdAction( $id ){ 


        $this->view->setVar("output", $this->gamesModel->getStatusById( $id ) );

        $this->view->pick("layouts/json_output");

    }

}
```

**Table**

[image]

../game/getStatusById/3  shows 0 as it should when I uncomment findFirst()

Otherwise i get

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::$active ..\json_output.phtml on
>   line 3

am i missing something?

I have defined the charset as UTF8 in my connection.

Comment: GamesModel::findFirst(3) and GamesModel::findFirstById(3) also uses bound parameters internally

Comment: are you saying that findFirst() automatically binds the parameters? because in the example page it suggests that you need to do it to eliminate the risk of SQL injection

Comment: Yes, it automatically binds parameters, you can add a log to your database connection and you can see how it pass the parameter with a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

I don't really understand why, but when hardcoding id in the bind parameter array (as string and int) i could use

```
echo $output->active
```

in the view, and this worked fine, however when binding id to the variable $id passed to getStatusByIdAction() i needed to  loop through the result.

```
foreach ($output as $outputRow) {
    echo $outputRow->active;
}
```

**something useful:**

var dumping the $result actually contains the query string and bound parameters.